# Выдает ошибку после минуты работы :list index out of range в функций get_last_update

Tags: python-3.x

```
class BotHandler:

    def __init__(self,token):
        self.token = token
        self.api_url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot{}/".format(token)

    def get_updates(self, offset=None, timeout=30):
        method = 'getUpdates'
        params = {'timeout': timeout, 'offset': offset}
        resp = requests.get(self.api_url + method, params)
        result_json = resp.json()['result']
        return result_json

    def get_last_update(self):
        get_result = self.get_updates()

        if len(get_result)>0:
            last_update = get_result[-1]
        else:
            last_update = get_result[len(get_result)]

        return last_update
```

Comment: Это `if len(get_result)>0:` можно заменить на `if get_result:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в `last_update = get_result[len(get_result)]`

---

А теперь я покажу на наглядном и простом примере почему:

```
# Создаем пустой список
items = []

# Размер 0
size = len(items)

# Выход за пределы границ: IndexError: list index out of range
items[size]
```

Потому что, список пустой.

Возможно, ветку `else` вообще нужно убрать.